# How to call simplemodal osx plugin programmatically?

Tags: macos, events, click, simplemodal

I've implemented the simplemodal plugin for JQuery. Very nice btw! Where I'm having an issue, is I have a list of links that are generated from a database, when I click one, I make a "load" call and add the results to my osx-modal-content div. How do I call the osx plugin after my load completes? If I add class=osx to my a href, the modal opens before the content get into the div.

My Function to load html:

```
function loadContent(id) {
        $("#osx-modal-dialog").load("Item.cfm?ID="+id+"");
        // call OSX here????
        $('#osx-modal-dialog').modal();
    }
```

My DIV:

```
<div id="osx-modal-dialog">
  <div id="osx-modal-content">
<div id="osx-modal-title">Title</div>
<div id="osx-modal-data">
    <h2>Summary</h2>
    <p>Description</p>
    <p><button class="simplemodal-close">Close</button> <span>(or press ESC or click the overlay)</span></p>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently the osx plugin is looking for input or a click event. I'm not sure how to script a 'click' event ofter my load. Or maybe there is a better way to call the plugin.

Includes:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

Modify the OSX content (I removed most of the content and added a placeholder):

```
<div id="osx-modal-content">
               <div id="osx-modal-title">OSX Style Modal Dialog</div>
               <div id="osx-modal-data">
                       <div id="osx-data-placeholder"></div>
                       <p><button class="simplemodal-close">Close</button> <span>(or press
ESC or click the overlay)</span></p>
               </div>
       </div>
```

Your loadContent function:

```
function loadContent(id) {
               var d = $('#osx-modal-content');

               // load your page
               $.get("Item.cfm?ID=" + id, function(data) {

                       // replace the placeholder with the results
                       $('#osx-data-placeholder', d[0]).html(data);

                       // open the osx modal
                       d.modal({
                               overlayId: 'osx-overlay',
                               containerId: 'osx-container',
                               closeHTML: '<div class="close"><a href="#"
class="simplemodal-close">x</a></div>',
                               minHeight:80,
                               opacity:65,
                               position:['0',],
                               overlayClose:true,
                               onOpen:OSX.open,
                               onClose:OSX.close
                       });
               });
       }
```

I haven't tested it, but I'm pretty sure this should do the trick.

-Eric

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I'm getting the error: OSX is not defined

All needed js files are getting loaded as well as osx.css. Is OSX not defined because the osx.js plugin hasn't been triggered?

Comment: I was assuming that you were using the js file that came with the OSX download - where the OSX var is defined. Make sure the file is loaded or add this code to that file.

Comment: Thanks for the help Eric. I pulled the Var OSX...code out of the plugin and added it to my script on the calling page...works fine..not ideal, but works.

Answer (score 0):

The load method has a callback parameter where you can supply a function that will be executed when the load has completed.  Use this callback to do trigger the dialog.

```
function loadContent(id) {
    $("#osx-modal-dialog").load("Item.cfm?ID="+id+"", function() {
        $('input.show-info').unbind('click') // remove any existing handlers
                            .click( function() { // bind click on button to show dialog
             $('#osx-modal-dialog').modal();
        });
    });
}
```

**Update**: I've updated this to show how to add a click handler in the callback of load(), but I don't know what event you want to handle nor what element the event is triggered on.  I'll assume that you want to show the dialog when you click a button with class "show-info".

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I can get the modal to open, my issue is calling the plugin to open the modal. The osx example has a link ex:<a href='#' class='osx'>Demo</a> and in the plugin osx.js: $("input.osx, a.osx").click(function...

I need to simulate a click for 'a' with a class=osx.

Comment: Do you mean how do you call the loadContent() method?  The code you are referencing is not simulating a click, but rather adding a handler that responds to a click and opens the dialog.  You already have part of the handler -- the loadContent() function.  All you need is a way to call loadContent() with the correct id based on some user action.  I can add a sample click handler definition, but without more info on your html it may not be of much help.

Comment: I have a link that pass the ID to the loadcontent function(<a  href="javascript:loadContent('1234');">). Everything works as is. Instead of calling "$('#osx-modal-dialog').modal();" I'd like to utilize the osx plugin, But I'm not sure how to get it invoked after my data loads. If I add class=osx to my link, the osx plugin fires off before the data loads into the div and I'm one click ahead of data that gets displayed.  So, I need to either simulate the a.osx click...or modify the plugin test to something I can invoke from the load.callback()

Comment: When do you want the dialog displayed?  When they click on something else?  What is that other thing?

Comment: If you'd show more of your html I might be able to help more.

Comment: I appreciate your willingness to help. The page lives on an intranet, I'll throw everything on public website tonight and send a link. Thanks again.